# Python KeyError: 'flags', when running BlueBorne script

Tags: python, python-2.x, scapy

I am trying to run the file [l2cap_infra.py](https://github.com/ArmisSecurity/blueborne/blob/master/l2cap_infra/l2cap_infra.py) with Python 2, but I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "l2cap_infra.py", line 524, in <module>
    main(*sys.argv[1:])
  File "l2cap_infra.py", line 508, in main
    l2cap_loop, _ = create_l2cap_connection(src_hci, dst_bdaddr, pcap_path=pcap_path)
  File "l2cap_infra.py", line 489, in create_l2cap_connection
    handle_information_negotiation_process(l2cap_loop)
  File "l2cap_infra.py", line 425, in handle_information_negotiation_process
    l2cap_loop.send(info_req)
  File "l2cap_infra.py", line 142, in send
    self._sock.send(packet)
  File "l2cap_infra.py", line 213, in send
    self.send_fragment(Raw(str(l2cap)[i:i+L2CAP_DEFAULT_MTU]), i == 0)
  File "l2cap_infra.py", line 223, in send_fragment
    hci = HCI_Hdr() / HCI_ACL_Hdr(handle=scapy_handle, flags=scapy_flags) / frag
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/base_classes.py", line 227, in __call__
    i.__init__(*args, **kargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 135, in __init__
    self.fields[f] = self.get_field(f).any2i(self, v)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 170, in get_field
    return self.fieldtype[fld]
KeyError: 'flags'
```

This might be a version conflict; I had a similar problem and I had to edit a file in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/`.

What code do I have to change in that linked file or in one of my pip libraries to make this code work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems it's a compatibility issue between *BlueBorne* and *Scapy*.

You (most likely) have installed the latest *Scapy* version (*v2.**4.0***), which dropped the ***fields*** *kwarg* from `scapy.layers.bluetooth.HCI_ACL_Hdr`'s initializer, while *BlueBorne* (*l2cap_infra.py*, and possibly others) was not updated (or branched) accordingly.

The latest version that still has it is *v2.**3.3*** ([[GitHub]: secdev/scapy - (v2.3.3) scapy/scapy/layers/bluetooth.py](https://github.com/secdev/scapy/blob/v2.3.3/scapy/layers/bluetooth.py)).

Possible solutions:

- Uninstall your current *Scapy* version (`pip uninstall scapy`) and install *v2.3.3* (`pip install scapy==2.3.3`). Probably, this is the simplest (and most suitable) for you ([[PyPI]: scapy 2.3.3](https://pypi.org/project/scapy/2.3.3))
- Submit a bug to *BlueBorne* and wait for them to add support for newer *Scapy* versions
- Fix it yourself ("*fields*" (*v2.3.3*) to "*PB*" + "*BC*" (*v2.4.0*) *kwargs* conversion), and maybe submit a patch :)